# How to automate Methods mapping between two java classes?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, refactoring, automated-refactoring

**I have a legacy springMvc project and i want to refactor all  the controllers to  return ResponseEntity object rather then returning Model object which is returned by  default.**

**I am looking for a way to map functions in Map class to ResponseEntity class .**

**I have seen people recommend to use Regular expression as a solution to refactor all the methods.**

**I need to know your opinion  about implementing Regex as solution in terms of advantages / drawbacks for  using regex in this scenario.**

**In addition it would be helpful if you can suggest other solutions.**

**please take a look at the attached code for more details.**

**return Model object to the view**

```
@GetMapping("/getData")
    public String getData(Model model) {
       
        model.addAttribute("message", "springMvc");
        
        return "viewPage";
    }
```

**return ResponseEntity object as  a json format**

```
@GetMapping("/getData")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String,String>>  getData() {

        Map<String,String> map = new  HashMap<>();
        map.put("message", "springMvc");
       
        return  new ResponseEntity.Ok().body(map);
    }
```

Comment: why do you want to do that ?

Comment: Are there any HTML files in this _legacy Spring MVC project_ ? The `return "viewPage";` indicates that a _view_ (HTML-template) is filled with the previously prepared _model_ (that's "MVC"). What is your plan to change / refactor?

Comment: There are HTML files but the frontend will be rebuild using angular. I just need to refactor my controller to return json instead of model views.

Comment: @ggr because i want the controller to return only responseEntity (json object) so it can be consumed by angular in the frontend.

Comment: just return your object, a bean, DTO

Comment: @ggr can you please write some code to explain your idea?

Comment: @GetMapping("/getData")
    public Data  getData() {

        return myService.getData()
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this problem is faced by someone in the future i would like to share that I have found a convenient way to do the refactoring of the code by using AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) which gives you a lot more control over the code comparing to using Regex.

you can check the library repository :

- https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser

Note that AST is used by IDEs and Static analysis tools such as SonarQube

Answer (score 0):

Regex cannot be used in your context. There are certainly too many special cases to change, it is not just a question of changing a string. JavaParser is a good candidate.

Comment: That what i have found thnks for confirming that.